# MVC mapping viewmodels to POCOs

Tags: entity-framework-4, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application using EF 4 and POCOs. One of the main challenges that I have is how to map a ViewModel to a POCO.

For example:

I have two POCO object -> User and Order. Furthemore I have a ViewModel --> UserOrderModel containing both models. Whenever some data is posted I would like to map the UserOrderModel to a User and an Order object. It is pretty straightforward to do this (perhaps just map on request in the controller) but I am wondering if there is a nice, clean solution for that problem (I was initially thinking of creating a generic mapping interace for all view models so that they must define how to map themselves to a POCO object)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a job for **[AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)**

Great example [here](http://www.bengtbe.com/blog/post/2009/04/14/Using-AutoMapper-to-map-view-models-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) on mapping MVC ViewModel's to POCO's.

Comment: Interesting, definitely worth looking into it.